# Core web vitals and web components - CLS

Tags: web-component, core-web-vitals

*For to optimize a website for WEB Vitals of google, one of the most common causes of a poor CLS is:
Images, Ads, embeds, and iframes without dimensions*

And the web component? How we can create a web component that no trigger cls? With a placeholder? With fixed dimensions?

Any suggestion?

Comment: A Web Component by itself is a **container** for DOM content. It is that **DOM content** that triggers Cumulative Layout Shifts. So a Web Component is basically no different than a **regular ``<DIV>``**

Answer (score 1):

Can you try testing your site in Chrome Canary? Several CLS bugs were recently fixed that incorrectly attributed layout shifts to web components in the first frame they were rendered.

I always recommend measuring Web Vitals in Chrome Canary in order to get the most accurate results.

Also, FYI, if you want to follow changes and bug fixes for each of the metrics, you can do so here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/speed/metrics_changelog/README.md